# Adding a new Identity column without exclusively locking the table

Tags: sql-server

I have a script from the DEV which I need to move it to prod. I am litte bit worried about the impact and testing it on a copy of prod data in a lower env. This table is about 193G and has ~24M records.
My script is still executing for more than 5 hours. What I have observed from the first 3 Alter statements, the table is locked exclusively while dropping existing primary key and adding a new identity column and my basic select query just runs forever.

And I am guessing adding new pk constraint is also going to lock the table and the other non clustered index creation as well (despite having with online=ON parameter) for the reason it is wrapped in a single transaction.

Is there a better way of doing this ( a truly online way or very less downtime).

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
GO

ALTER TABLE [tblname] DROP CONSTRAINT [PK_tblname]; 
GO

ALTER TABLE [tblname] ALTER COLUMN [ColumnB] nvarchar(200) NULL;
GO

ALTER TABLE [tblname] ADD [Id] bigint NOT NULL IDENTITY;
GO

ALTER TABLE [tblname] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_tblname] PRIMARY KEY ([Id]);
GO

CREATE INDEX [IX_tblname_ColumnA] ON [tblname] ([ColumnA]) WITH (ONLINE = ON);
GO

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [IX_tblname_ColumnB] ON [tblname] ([ColumnB]) WHERE [ColumnB] IS NOT NULL WITH (ONLINE = ON);
GO

COMMIT;
GO
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the current table definition including all indexes? Is the current PK the clustered index?

Comment: Hi @MartinSmith- Yes the current PK is the clustered Index. and the table has 3 other non unique non clustered indexes.

Comment: Dropping the primary key will drop the clustered index then and mean that all non clustered indexes get updated to reference the physical RID - and then when you add the PK this will need to rewrite the entire table and all NCIs again.

Comment: If you are concerned about availability and can't take an outage for this then probably best off just creating a new table and copying all rows to it and then keeping both tables in synch until ready to cut over to it.